# Converting $(-5, 5, 5)$ from rectangular to cylindrical coordinates.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, cylindrical-coordinates

One of my homework questions on WebAssign asks that I convert the point $(-5, 5, 5)$ from rectangular to cylindrical coordinates such that $r\geq 0$ and $0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi $.

Seems pretty straightforward, but the system won't accept my answer.

**My approach**

$r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} = \sqrt{25 + 25} = \sqrt{2(25)} = 5\sqrt2$

$\theta = arctan(5/-5) = -\pi/4 = 7\pi/4$ (since they want $\theta $ to be positive)

$z = z = 5$

Wouldn't the point be $(r, \theta, z) = (5\sqrt2, 7\pi/4, 5)$? Did I make a mistake somewhere?

Comment: methinks your angle should be $\theta=\frac{3}{4}\pi$ seeing as the point $(-5,5)$ lies on a line of slope $-1$ going through the origin and for a similar line with slope $1$ you'd have $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Comment: Ooooh, so it's in the 2nd quadrant. Okay, I see. Thank you! Update: Yep, the system now accepted the answer. That was it.